# Переезд на sass

Tags: sass, css

Хочу перевести один из рабочих проектов на sass. Проект уже достаточно большой и в нем очень много css файлов. Поскольку хотелось бы сделать плавный поэтапный переезд то нет желания переписывать сейчас весь код на sass. То есть новые куски писались бы на sass а старые медленно переводились бы из css в sass. Я могу просто переименовать все *.css файлы в* .sass и оставить там внутри все тот же css? Он на выдаче после обработки sass'овским компилятором будет валидным ccs'ом?

Comment: [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)-то прикольней.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть ещё переходный вариант: scss.
На мой взгляд это оптимальное решение в вашем случае.
традиционный css является вполне допустимым вариантом scss.
Но для sass ситаксис css неприемлем, он будет восприниматься как синтаксическая ошибка.